Is my fantasy creature realistic?
I am curious whether the behavior and attributes of this species are within the realm of possibility.
Light Seekers are nocturnal mammals characterized by furry jet-black bodies, along with glowing white eyes and teeth. Their fur is dense and velvety, which not only aids in camouflage but also helps insulate them against the colder nighttime temperatures. An average adult Light Seeker stands about three feet tall, with elongated limbs and a lithe body structure that allows them to move silently. Their eyes are especially large, adapted to low light, and can reflect light like those of a cat, which adds to their unsettling allure. The contrast between their white teeth and eyes starkly highlights their presence, especially in dark environments.
Behavior:
Light Seekers exhibit a behavior pattern that revolves around their attraction to light. When darkness falls, they venture out in search of illuminated areas. Much like moths drawn to a flame, they are compelled to approach any source of light they can find. Their fascination with light is both passive and persistent, as they can spend hours simply staring at it without blinking, seemingly entranced, even avoiding the need for food or water.
These creatures communicate through a series of low-frequency sounds reminiscent of purring or gentle chattering. While they are generally harmless, they can be social and curious, often forming small groups that explore light sources together. They have excellent night vision and a keen sense of smell, which aids in navigating through their dark environment.
Interaction with Humans:
Light Seekers generally do not pose any threat to humans. Their main interest lies in light rather than human interaction, and they will often retreat if startled or approached too quickly. If a door or window is left unlocked, they may wander into a home, captivated by the indoor lighting, but they usually do not engage with objects or attempt to cause damage. Their presence can, however, become quite unnerving, as anyone who spots them gazing silently through a window may be met with an instinctive fear.
Humans may find their behavior unsettling—not because they are inherently dangerous but due to the sudden appearance of these ghostly figures in the darkness. The sight of just their glowing eyes and gleaming teeth can provoke panic or fear, leading to misconceptions about their intentions. In rural areas or places where Light Seekers are commonly seen, locals often share ominous tales about them, describing them as ominous harbingers of bad luck or spirits of the night.

Do their eyes actually glow, or is it merely eyeshine? Aside from the problem that glowing eyes would have seeing past their own glow, it would be odd for them to be so fascinated with light sources when they themselves bioluminesce.

The creature seemed realistic until you got to "jet-black bodies" then it all fell to bits after that

Why are jet black bodies unrealistic? There are tons of animals with black fur. Dogs, bears, etc.

That makes sense, I'll make their eyes reflect but not glow themselves. What about their teeth? Could they be reflective too?

Comments beneath questions are not for discussions, nor a place for the OP to ask questions, they are for prompting the OP to improve/clarify the question. Could you please edit the question into something specific that can be answered with something other than opinion.

As long as the "glowing" eyes is the reflection like in cat's eyes, there is nothing physically unrealistic about the creature.
So, behavior ends up being the question.
Trying to think of why it does that, biologically is light good or just so different that it can't process what it sees?
What benefit does it get or did it get in the past that moving toward light gave it?
Is the creature naturally curious and there are no naturally occurring light sources at night (like no moon)?
Deer in the headlights refers to deers freezing when they see headlights.  Bright lights just don't occur at night and their brains just can't process it.

Worth emphasising that a nocturnal creature needs to get all non-sleep activities done at night, with hunting for prey presumably being the major activity.  If they spend all night every night staring at a light source then the species will go extinct from starvation as soon as there are humans who regularly have illumination at night.  (If they magically "feed" on light sources then "realistic" goes out the window.  No, mammals getting energy from light is nowhere near sufficient, even sunlight.)

Neither the characters nor the author need to actually know for sure. Author can just brainstorm and keep all the items as things different characters/cultures guess the reason to be. It wasn't until the invention of high speed cameras that we had one really good explanation for why bugs are attracted to light, and even that one is just a good hypothesis among slightly weaker hypotheses. People told stories with moths in them just fine the whole time.

What if the Light Seeker searches for light sources only when the moon is New, because it's evolved to use the moon's guidance and without it is confused and disoriented? Perhaps it hunts and lives its life regularly 90% of the time, but during those rare nights when the moon is not out, it acts differently.

@J.Rubio Nah. They're not attracted to light at all. They're receiving mission instructions from the Illuminati, who communicate with them using micro-flickers on the electrical grid which are too subtle for human eyes to detect. The truth is out there.
